# updating a single object key value inside array of objects react redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to update an object and its key value inside an array using react redux but as I am new to react and redux, so I am not finding a good way to do this and also the value, is not updating to.

Here is my action

```
export const addIngredientToMenuItemCartA = (menu_item_id,timestamp,ingrediant,ingrediant_type,selectedMenuItemIngrediantType)
=> async dispatch => {

    dispatch({
        type: ADD_INGREDIENT_TO_MENU_ITEM_CART,
        payload: {
            menu_item_id,
            timestamp,
            ingrediant,
            ingrediant_type,
            ingrediant_category_type_blue: selectedMenuItemIngrediantType
        }
    }); 
};
```

Here is my reducer

```
export default function(state=[],action){
    case ADD_INGREDIENT_TO_MENU_ITEM_CART:
                let menu_item_id = action.payload.menu_item_id;
                let ingrediant = action.payload.ingrediant;
                let timestamp = action.payload.timestamp;
                let items1 = state.slice();
                const itemIndexi1 = items1.findIndex(item => item.menu_item_id === menu_item_id);
                if(true){
                    items1[itemIndexi1].ingrediantTotal = ingrediant.price;
                }
                items1[itemIndexi1].ingrediants.push(ingrediant);
                return items1;
            default:
                return state;
        }
```

I have an array of the cart which has objects inside it and I want to find that specific objects and then update them but if I update them in the reducer then the values are not being changed in the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are mutating the objects.  There is a simple pattern to loop over the list and handle only the relevant item while creating new objects without mutations.

In your case, your code could look something like this:

```
case ADD_INGREDIENT_TO_MENU_ITEM_CART: {
    const { menu_item_id, ingrediant } = action.payload;

    const nextState = state.map(item => {
        if (item.menu_item_id !== menu_item_id) {
            // not our item, return it as is
            return item;
        }

        // this is our relevant item, return a new copy of it with modified fields
        return {
            ...item,
            ingrediantTotal: ingrediant.price,
            ingrediants: [
                ...item.ingrediants,
                ingrediant
            ]
        }
    });

    return nextState;
}
```

Keep in mind, `Objects` and `Arrays` are mutable so we can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) or `.slice` etc.

Comment: Thanks let me try it can you let me know why we can not use .slice() because at some stackover flow answers i have seen person using the slice method.

Comment: Because it's mutative.  You want to avoid direct mutation in redux.

Comment: You **can** use `.slice` i even stated it in my answer, the problem is that it will return a new array but won't create a deep copy (the objects inside it are the same) and you did mutate them. i used `.map` to return a new array while changing its values, and i used the spread syntax for both arrays and objects (i could use  `.slice` for the arrays as well)